# Put 2 or more lines in each facet using facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I have this simplified `df` which I'm using facet_wrap() to plot multiple variables:

```
Day <- (1:30)

Type <-  rep(c("A", "B","C"),10)

Value_1 <- runif(30, min=-1, max=2)
Value_2 <- runif(30, min=-1, max=2)

df <- tibble:: tibble(Day, Type, Value_1, Value_2)


 ggplot2:: ggplot(df, aes(x=Day, y=Value_1, color= Type))+
  geom_line()+
   facet_wrap(~Type)
```

My question is: **how I plot Value_1 and Value_2 in the same "facet"?**.
I.e, my plot would be exactly as the above, but two lines in each rectangle (one line for Value_A and another for Value_B).

I appreciate it if someone can help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this reshaping data to long:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
#Code
df %>% pivot_longer(-c(Day,Type)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Day, y=value, color= name,group=name))+
  geom_line()+
  facet_wrap(~Type)
```

Output:

[image]